# How to use varnish to pass data when the backend is ok && return the last normal beresq when the backend is down?

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I need varnish to return data directly and update cache at every time when the backend is ok. I also need varnish to return the last normal beresq data from the cache when the backend is down. How shuold I do with varnish?

Answer (score 1):

I just slove it. When backend is up, use req.hash_always_miss=true to pass data. When backend is down, make response to FEATCH_FAILED and use vcl_synth to restart recv.

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "4567";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss=true;
    } else {
        set req.hash_always_miss=false;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    return (abandon);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    return (restart);
}
```